# About Java arrays

Tags: java, arrays

This is the code I wrote about a prime number question using `java` but when I run the code it says something about `java` string formatter. Help me find out whats wrong please.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Hello {

public static void main(String args[]) {

    int checker=2;

    boolean [] prime= new boolean [1000];

    for(int i = 0; i < prime.length; i++)
        {
            prime[i] = true;
        }

    do
    {

    for(int i=2;i<prime.length;i++)
    {
        if((i % checker) == 0)
        {
            prime[i]=false;
        }
    }
    checker++;
    } while(checker!=999);

    for(int i = 0; i < prime.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.printf("%5c",prime[i]);
        }
 }
}
```

Comment: Please describe what goes wrong and what you have already tried.

Answer (score 3):

Your exception is not because of the array but because of the array *type*:

```
System.out.printf("%5c",prime[i]);
```

your `prime` array is a boolean array, whereas the string format `%c` expects a Unicode character. For boolean you'll need `%b` as such:

```
System.out.printf("%5b",prime[i]);
```

Comment: Note: It'll print `false` if `prime[i]` is `null`, should be aware of this.

Comment: @MarounMaroun how boolean primitive can be null?

Comment: @SashaSalauyou Indeed. As I said, I didn't note.

Answer (score 0):

Change your output to:

```
System.out.println(i + (prime[i] ? " is prime" : " is not prime"));
```

It uses [ternary operator](http://java.about.com/od/t/g/ternaryoperator.htm) as shortcut of `if (prime[i]) ... else ...` to generate the output like

```
1 is not prime
2 is prime
3 is prime
4 is not prime
...
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, a few words of explanation will help current and future readers understand this answer even better.

Answer (score 0):

For printing boolean you just print -

```
System.out.printf(prime[i]);
```

Or you may use `%b` as format specifier -

```
System.out.printf("%5b",prime[i]);
```